# how to tell if color is process or spot in adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How can I tell if a color is a process or spot color in adobe illustrator? How can I tell if a color is a process or spot color in adobe illustrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select an object.. look at the Color Panel.

Spot.....

[image: spot]

CMYK .....

[image: cmyk]

Alternatively, you can open the Separations Preview Panel (Window > Separations Preview) and toggle visibility icons (the little eyeballs) to show and hide specific color types.

[image: seps]

Comment: my color palettte looks like a rainbow of gradients. How do I fix that?

Comment: Nevermind i see it

Answer (score 3):

There is an easier way. Even in "rainbow of gradients" mode. Just look at the swatch thumbnail.

in this example you can see non-global process, global process, and spot just by the indicator in the bottom right.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I would do (Window > Separations Preview).

I've had spot colors used, and when I look at the color panel it appears like a 4cp, but is actually a PMS color. When I used Separations Preview, it showed what really was a PMS color.

Comment: that was already mentioned in another answer. If you want to know more about the site, please see [help]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!